# How to calculate page response time?

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

I have a basic question. How to calculate the page response time?

Comment: Please add to the question what you tried already, which protocol do you use, and what exactly do you call "page response time". Be very specific if you want a good answer.

Comment: Is this in general, or in LoadRunner specifically?

Comment: Calculate or measure?

Comment: training is the path to enlightenment

Answer (score 0):

Page loading is basically a client side process which is done by the browser and depends on the Network Bandwidth.
While HP Loadrunner can only help you measure the time taken by server to process the request.It includes: Time taken to send the request + the time taken by Server to process the request + time taken by server to respond to client side(Browser).